# Login Screen Not Honoring Preferences

Tags: login-screen

I have both an iMac Pro (2017) and a Macbook Air M1 each running Big Sur 11.3.1.  My laptop is correctly showing my customized login screen and requires both a username and password.  However, the desktop will not.  Instead it shows just a password (with the last user logged on) and the default image.  I have tried setting it in system preferences as well as via the terminal.

Here are the current login settings:

```
sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow              
Password:
{
    AccountInfo =     {
        FirstLogins =         {
            redacted = 1;
        };
        MaximumUsers = 1;
        OnConsole =         {
        };
    };
    DesktopPicture = "/Library/Desktop Pictures/sts30nightlaunch_nasa.jpg";
    GuestEnabled = 0;
    LoginwindowText = Antifragile;
    OptimizerLastRunForBuild = 42212896;
    OptimizerLastRunForSystem = 184746240;
    PowerOffDisabled = 0;
    SHOWFULLNAME = 0;
    UseVoiceOverLegacyMigrated = 1;
    lastUser = loggedIn;
    lastUserName = redacted;
}
```

Everything seems set up fine, but it will not honor the showFullName or DesktopPicture settings for some reason.

Edit:  For clarity, the plist above is on the desktop Mac which is not displaying the username/password dialog.  My desire is to have all machines require both username and password.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you edit this to state explicitly what end state you want for both Macs?

Comment: Is FileVault enabled?

Comment: Both have FileVault enabled.

Comment: I'm looking to have both username and password required on both the laptop and desktop.